# Mo' Creatures spawning in the Aether on 1.10.2, how do I disable that?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-aether

Mo' Creatures mobs are all over the Aether (using Aether Legacy)

I'm playing on 1.10.2, using the latest Aether Legacy and Mo' Creatures (and Custom 
Mob Spawner) available for those versions.

Is it possible to disable Mo' Creatures mobs spawning in the Aether, and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: This question is not asking for *technical* support.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer to this!

I had to go into the config files:

```
config/CustomSpawner/aether/Creatures/DRZHARK.cfg
```

I then changed all instances of "canSpawn=true" to "canSpawn=false."

This may work, I will edit my comment if it does.

Answer (score -1):

honestly? the easiest way would be to take out Mo-Creatures. but im not sure you want to do that. this? this is just a fall back plan.